# Population of /etc/resolv.conf upon new server installation

Tags: linux, centos

I purchased two Linux servers that have CentOS preinstalled.
One was bare whilst one has many other common packages installed(httpd, bind, mysql, php).

I purchased one of these servers with 2 additional IPS which I noticed both show up inside the */etc/resolv.conf* assigned as *nameservers* along with the servers IP itself also assigned as a *nameserver*(by sever IP I mean the IP which I also use to login to SSH).

Whereas my other server(no additional IP's), has only 2 IPS present assigned as *nameservers*, but neither of these IP's are my server's IP(by server IP I mean the IP I use to Login to SSH) and are both from very different ranges.

I didn't create or edit either of the */etc/resolv.conf*, I am curious how the IPS got there, is this a automatic network assignment? a centOS assignment, or is it done by the webhost?

I am curious as to why one */etc/resolv.conf* has my servers IP listed as a nameserver, and one hasn't got it listed at all. - Is this a error?

Seems not very ordered.

Comment: If you didn't install the systems, perhaps the previous owner left them there?

Comment: @Andrew They was fresh installs according to my webhost. Can I use these nameserver IP's in a zone file like NS1.mydomain.com IN NS IP(resolv.conf ip 1), NS2.mydomain.com IN NS IP(resolv.conf ip2)?

Answer (score 1):

Could be DHCP server populating your DNS server information.

```
# Sample /etc/dhcpd.conf
# (add your comments here) 
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option routers 192.168.1.254;
**option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;**
```

Comment: I dont appear to have one of those files on either server, Tried using find / -name dhcpd.conf

Comment: It would be on the dhcp server from which your servers got their IPs.

Comment: is there anyway to echo the file? or parts of it?